# How to display the current user name in a parameter field using crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I want to display the current user name in a "Prepared By" Field(Parameter Field) of a crystal report using vb.net. How can i achieve that? I have the current username in a string variable. Now how can i link it to the Prepared By field?

Please provide me some input.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where you storing this data? Hopefully some kind of database, if so just pull the field in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, you must have the field in your report first though...

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim Report1 As New CrystalReport1

  Report1.SetParameterValue("crTextBox", Form1.TextBox1.Text)
  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
 End Sub
```

In the SetParameterValue you specify the field name from your report and the field you want from your form or whatever it maybe; in your case your variable.